# Doing work that takes a long time when app has been backgrounded

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, background, multitasking

I want a method to work in background until a duration specified by the user (let's say 20 minutes) elapses. I know it's not possible, because Apple allows the app to work for a maximum of 10 minutes in the background. Unfortunately FireDate works with `UILocalNotification`s only. I also read about `performSelector:Selector:WithObject:afterDelay:` method but I'm not sure if that will work in the background or not. Kindly give me suggesstions and code snippets (if any).

Comment: What type of processing are you looking to do in the background?

Comment: What exactly is your question here? I see a lot of dialoguing, but no question mark anywhere. (Also note that the "double dot" `..` is not a punctuation mark in English.)

Comment: @jeremy, First of all sorry for (..). Secondly, I have been asked for the best way to send my own method in Background thread.

Comment: @blounty, I want very simple interaction with the ringer volume. 
@bshirley, Yes its IOS 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two methods that will be of use:

[NSObject](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) `-(void)performSelectorInBackground:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg`

[UIApplication](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
`- (UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier)beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:(void(^)(void))handler`

local notifications can be used if you want the user to re-launch, but if they don't click through to the app, then your app never knows about it

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i know exactly about the second method you mentioned "beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler", it doesnt allow our app to stay in background for more then 10 mins, so not of my use because in my case the user can give 60 mins also ! and i am not sure about performSelectorInBackground that will it work if my app is terminated by the user ??

Comment: and one thing more to ask, does Selector (which would be my custom method) in performSelectorInBackground allowes parameters to be passed??

Comment: the performSelector method runs your method in a background process, you _can_ pass it a parameter - the second would need to be called, likely on the mail thread, when you started the background process, and like you said, they estimate 10 minutes, but there is no guarantee it will be that long, or they won't allow more at some point  -- something that requires running for an hour seems suspect, are you sure there's not a better solution (than the brute force one you're hoping for?)

Comment: if you are running the the background for location services, audio playback, or VOIP, there are other solutions [Background Execution](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5)

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation :) and sir my app's scenario needs to be in background that is why i want to work with this properly. I came to know from somewhere that in IOS 4, there is no limitation of time if you want to work with beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler . I will try both the things then will let you know. Thanks a lot once again for your guidance :)